# Zend 2 determinate routed / used Navigation in View

Tags: php, navigation, zend-framework2

How can i determinate in which navigation the request is routed in View (/ Template)?

I have two Navigations:
1 - User Navigation
2 - Admin Navigation

If User is logged in system as Admin, both navbars should be accessible (switched via triggerdiv)
So if the Admin triggers a link on the Usernavigation i would like to show the Usernavigation after the new request - if he triggers an Adminlink i would like to show the AdminNavbar.

Here the navigations array from module.config.php:

```
'navigation' => array(
    'default' => array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Home',
            'route' => 'user',
            'resource' => 'navigation',
            'privilege' => 'home',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Login',
            'route' => 'auth',
            'resource' => 'navigation',
            'privilege' => 'auth',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Logout',
            'route' => 'logout',
            'resource' => 'navigation',
            'privilege' => 'logout',
        ),
    ),
    'admin' => array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Home',
            'route' => 'admin',
            'resource' => 'navigation',
            'privilege' => 'home',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Users',
            'route' => 'users',
            'resource' => 'navigation',
            'privilege' => 'users',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Logout',
            'route' => 'logout',
            'resource' => 'navigation',
            'privilege' => 'logout',
        ),
    ),
),
```

if possible i would like to know and proof for the navigation keys from the navigation array.
i have no clue how i could access them, neither i found some helping links till now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came now up with following solution:

every controller is extended from Guest / User or Admin controller

in construct of extended controller i set the navigation key":

```
protected $_sNavigationKey = 'guest';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->getEventManager()->attach('dispatch', function ($e)
    {
        $this->layout()->setVariable('sNavigationKey', $this->_sNavigationKey);
    });
}
```

now i can check / show the right navigation in the layout via proof of *$sNavigationKey*